# what does function symbol $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ means?

Tags: functions

I have just started learning functions.

I am troubled by this:   $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ where $\mathbb R$ represents the set of real numbers and $\mathbb Z$ represents the set of integers.

> What does this statement mean when it is mentioned infant of a function such as $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ where $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For any sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f:X\to Y$ means that $f$ is a function that takes as input elements of $X$, and gives as output values of $Y$.

In your case, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$ are sets, so when we write $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$, we mean that $f$ is a function that takes any real number as input, and gives out an integer as output.

Comment: But there exist functions such as f:x = x+0.5, where x = 1 which is real number but the output is 1.5, 1.5 is not an integer, do we ignore this input such as 1,2,3,4...... which results output as Real Number instead of integer?

Comment: @JaySun In that case, you're not allowed to say $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$, since as you've pointed out, the output isn't always an integer even though the input comes from $\Bbb R$. You say $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ instead, or $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$, or whatever suits your needs at the moment. When I write $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$, that doesn't do anything to $f$. It's just me promising that whatever $f$ is, it will behave in a certain manner. It's up to me to make sure that that promise is kept when I give a more detailed desctiption or formula. Saying $f(x) = x+0.5$ breaks that promise.

Comment: That being said, be aware that the expression "$f(x) = x+0.5$" might carry a different meaning. Instead of saying what the function $f$ does, it could instead be asking about what $x$ makes the left-hand side equal to the right-hand side. This is entirely valid, even if $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$, since even with real input and (always, guaranteed) integer output, there might be some real input values such that applying $f$ amounts to adding $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is it takes a real number as an input value ($x$) and outputs or maps to a integral value

For example, f(2.5) = 3, f(2.4) = 3, f(2) = 2. All the values between the parentheses are the inputs or $x$ values and must be a real number. The values after the equal are the out puts, which are and must be integers.

Comment: Does that means even if f(2.5)=3.5 by default, however due to the condition f:R→Z, the answer will still be 3 because 3 is an integer but 3.5 is not?

Comment: No, I f:R->Z implies that the output of any function that takes in a real value, must be integer. So f(x) = x wouldn't be right because it can sometimes output a non integer value. You defined f(x) = ceil(x), which incidentally is good because that means you are mapping any real number to some integer. There isn't just one function that maps R to Z

Answer (score 1):

In the context of functions the statement $f:A\to B$ means exactly that:

- $f\subseteq A\times B$
- For every $a\in A$ there is a unique $b\in B$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z$ denotes a function then the statement $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$ means exactly that: $$f=\{\langle x,\lceil x\rceil\rangle\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$$